# How to input a different value for "X1" in the HTML command id="X1"

Tags: html, variables, input

Sorry - I've searched but don't seem to be able to find an answer.
In my HTML code I have the line:

```
    <p id = "X1"></p>
```

At present I have to edit the file to change X1 to X2, or X3, or X4 etc.

Is there a way of simply user inputting X2 or X3 or X4 etc which will then be substituted for X1 in the HTML command line and then execute the action associated with the line.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to change the ID of the `<p>` tag when a user inputs some value with that value, right?

Comment: Yes. Instead of having to edit the HTML code file to change X1 to X2 (or some other value) I want to be able to enter, say, X3 and then for the code to be executed with X3 instead of X1.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of methods to change the value of 'id' attribute of a element according to the user input,

One of the simplest is using a 'select' element, like this

```
<p id="X1">Change</p>

<select class="selector" onchange="document.querySelector('p').id=this.value; console.log(document.querySelector('p').id)">
    <option value="X1" selected>X1</option>
    <option value="X2">X2</option>
    <option value="X3">X3</option>
    <option value="X4">X4</option>
</select>
```

Here, the value to be change are previously set as options for 'select'. According to the users selection the 'p' tag's 'id' updates by the help of in-built 'onchange' function .

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code as follows but it didn't work. What's wrong: 
<p id="X1"></p>
<select class="selector" onchange="document.querySelector('p').id=this.value; console.log(document.querySelector('p').id)">
    <option value="X1" selected>X1</option>
    <option value="X2">X2</option>
    <option value="X3">X3</option>   
</select>
<P>
<span id="X1"></span>
<span id="X2"></span>
<span id="X3"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("X1").innerHTML = 'Option1 '
document.getElementById("X2").innerHTML = 'Option2 '
document.getElementById("X3").innerHTML = 'Option3 '
</script>

Comment: Do you want to change the innerHTML of the 'span' elements by picking a option from the 'select' element?

Comment: Without trying to code it, my spec is a) to input a value X1 or X2 or X3; b) to use that value in the code <p id="X1 ro 2 or 2"></p>; and c) for that to activate the line document.getElementById("X1 or 2 or 3").innerHTML = 'Option1 '

Comment: As you need to change the innerHTML according to the 'p' tag's id instead of onchange you can use addEventListener with event as 'change' and for the function you can use some condition like 'if (document.querySelector('p').id == "X1"){document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Option1 '}

Comment: Thanks.  I really am most grateful for your help. I’m just stuck on one thing now. You’ve shown me how to SELECT a value of X1 or X2 or X3 or X4.   Now all I need to do is to use that value to replace X1 in the html code <p id = “X1”>. How do I do that?

Comment: You already got the solution through the answer " onchange="document.querySelector('p').id=this.value; " this function gets the value selected and replace the 'p' tag's id with it

Comment: <body>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="document.querySelector('p').id=this.value; ">
  <option value="X1">X1
  <option value="X2">X2
  <option value="X3">X3
</select>
<p id="X1"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "Option: " + x;
}
document.getElementById("X1").innerHTML = "Option is X1";
document.getElementById("X2").innerHTML = "Option is X2";
document.getElementById("X3").innerHTML = "Option is X3";
</script>

Comment: Thanks. I got the code as above. But I need to id=this.value term in the first line to use that value in the line  <p id="X1"></p> instead of X1. I've clearly missed something rather basic.

Comment: May be this is the solution you searching for https://codepen.io/Kumara2mahe/pen/NWywbEq

Comment: Thanks but I've done that and its not quite what I want. I don't want to put the if statements in the script (because in my more complicated version they already have if statement associated with them). I've actually reposted my question (together with the latest version of my code)  thanks to your help in order to focus on what now doesn't work.